# How add the new I item every time when we click on button

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, append

In my application I have two select dropdowns and below the dropdowns I have one button .

**.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <select class="form-control whenI" id="power" required>
              <option value="" disabled selected>Select one</option>
              <option *ngFor="let value of values" >{{value}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
<select class="form-control whenI" id="power" required>
              <option value="" disabled selected>Select one</option>
              <option *ngFor="let value of values" >{{value}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

<span ><i class="icon icon-add"></i>Add new Habit
      </span>
```

My requirement is when I click on the add icon It should append or add the above two dropdowns every time when we click on the item.

Can anyone helpme on the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `*ngIf` to read a boolean `shouldShow` that we turn true/false with click listener on the `Add new Habit` icon. `ng-container` is used to hold the template variable, but unlike `div, span` etc. it won't get rendered on the DOM.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="shouldShow">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <select class="form-control whenI" id="power" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select one</option>
        <option *ngFor="let value of values">{{ value }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <select class="form-control whenI" id="power" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select one</option>
        <option *ngFor="let value of values">{{ value }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
<br /><br />
<span (click)="onAdd()"><i class="icon icon-add"></i>Add new Habit </span>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  shouldShow: boolean = false;

  onAdd() {
    console.log('doing it');
    this.shouldShow = !this.shouldShow;
  }
}
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cuj5z7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thanks @ Joosep.P , so is it possible to write the push or append child instead of the above , if it is then Please help me on this

Comment: Please elaborate by what you mean with append? Appending elements is possible: https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/met_node_appendchild.asp but that is not the "Angular way". Using structuring directives is the way `*ngFor, *ngIf` etc.

Comment: Thanks it is absolutely working for me ,But small thing is while addign the new elements I have to add the space after every dropdown I use dmargin-top but not working can you please edit the above code foraddign teh space after each dropdown

Comment: Added `<div class="row" style="padding: 0  0 10px 0">` so each element will receive padding of 10px to bottom.

Comment: last thing is I have one close button onright side of added items like <i class="icon icon-close" type="button" aria-hidden="true"></i> It has to appear in every append item wnd when we click on item the dropdown has to remove, could you halp me on this

Comment: I added a way to remove items. For further questions please make a new question and provide code and examples of what you have so far. Otherwise this question will get saturated.